# Browser popup event capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to capture event of confirm popup generated by browsers.

I have an application wherein I try to open my file in Visual Studio Code using:

```
<a href="vscode://file/Users/abc/Desktop/about.html">Launch VS Code</a>
```

On click of this link, browser asks me **Open Visual Studio Code?** and Yes or No.

Can I capture that event of user on that popup and do some other task? Thanks in advance

**----------------- Partial Solution -----------------**

`<a (click)="openVSCode()">Launch VS Code</a>`

```
function openVSCode(){
  window.open('vscode://file/Users/abc/Desktop');
  window.open('vscode://file/Users/abc/Desktop/about.html');
}
```

The only downside to this is that there will be 2 browser generated popups opening at the same time. Else this fix seems to work.